# Some per-site metas have the incorrect blue "main site" theme instead of the correct black on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, per-site-meta

**Summary**: Unlike the desktop site, all mobile main sites (except SO and its language variants <s>and A51</s>) have the same blue theme and all mobile meta sites (except bugged ones) have the same black theme. However three "bugged" mobile meta sites erroneously carry out a blue theme.

As a mobile web user of the Stack Exchange for over a year, I'm familiar with the web page designs.

When I'm visiting Android Enthusiasts, Super User, Unix & Linux, I get this blue theme

[image: Super User]

When I'm visiting **Meta** Stack Exchange, **Meta** Stack Overflow, English Language & Usage **Meta**, I get this black theme

[image: Meta]

When I'm visiting Software Recommendations ***Meta***... **Wait, it's blue???**

[image: SoftwareRecs Meta]

I'm sure this is not my browser's bug, but I don't mind telling you it's **Google Chrome for Android version 59.0.3071.125** from Google Play.

Some blue metas (<s>this list may be incomplete</s>):

- [Japanese Language](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com)
- [Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com)
- [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com)

**Edit**: I finished searching. These are the only 3 bugged meta sites (as of July 8, 2017)

Comment: I've browsed the three sites just now and can confirm that this bug still exists.